# Appcelerator: Detect when user presses home button (iOS & Android)

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I want to detect when the user presses the home button in Android and iOS and then logout from the session. Is there any way to do that?

On iOS I tried to use the Titanium.App.pause listener and it works when I press the home button, but the problem is that this listener is also triggered when I do other things inside the app, like opening the gallery or the camera from the app or even using the control center.

On Android I tried a similar thing. But I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is subtle difference between pause and paused eventlisteners. Paused only detect when pressed home button on iPhone while pause always trigger when there is some interruptions into app like showing alert. Have a look into docs.
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App-event-pause
http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.App-event-paused

You can use whatever depending upon your requirement. For Android have look into this post that might be helpful for pause/resume Android.

http://www.tidev.io/2014/01/28/paused-resumed-events-on-android/

Comment: I used the paused event listener on iOS and it works fine, but the bencoding.android.tools is not working as expected on Android.

When I try to use the camera (Ti.Media.showCamera) from my app or when I try to open the gallery (Ti.Media.openPhotoGallery), the app is executing the code from that post, so it logs out.

Comment: So you have to figure out something else for it to work out correctly for Android. May be you set some global bool to indicate if pause is due to soft interruption as you always know when you are going to open camera or gallery and then in this case don't execute your logout logic.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is no event to detect home button pressed then to use pasue/resume event.

You can do one thing though, use boollean global variable to store whether gallery or camera or other events done which pauses app to background. That way you can catch home button clicked.

Comment: Well what I did is setting that global variable to false before I open the camera/gallery and then setting it back to true after the user gets the photo.

But the problem now is that I don't know how to do the same thing when opening pdf files.

My code looks like this:
    Ti.Android.currentActivity.startActivity(Ti.Android.createIntent({
action : Ti.Android.ACTION_VIEW,
type : 'application/pdf',
data : appfilepath
}));

Comment: you can set it after starting that activity

Answer (score 0):

Detecting Home Button presses relates to detecting if the app pauses or resumes, in iOS this has been rather easy in the past but for Android this has been very hard. I have been using tool such as the `bencoding.android.tools` module for this for a long time. With this you basically check every second if the app is still in the background.

With the introduction of Hyperloop we now have access to native classes so I have now built and released and Hyperloop Module for this:

https://github.com/dieskim/Appcelerator.Hyperloop.appPauseResume

In this modules iOS uses core T.App EventListeners pause and resume, while Android uses Narive Java Classes via Hyperloop and a setInterval to check and detect

Here is an Example of how you would listen for the pause and resume event and thus be able to determine if the home button was pressed:

```
// require appPauseResumeModule
var appPauseResume = require('appPauseResume');
// run appPauseResume and add resume and pause callbacks
appPauseResume({pause: function(){
                    Ti.API.info("appPauseResume - pause - Home pressed");
                },
                resume: function(){
                    Ti.API.info("appPauseResume - resume");
                },
                setIntervalTime: 1000,  // Optional - Default: 1000 miliseconds (1 second) 
});
```